# Makefile.am create empty directory

Tags: autotools, directory-structure, automake

Using autotools, I need to create an empty directory tree when typing make install, like:

```
/etc/myprg/
|-- foo
```

right now, I do this by specifying empty targets, like this:

```
myprgdir = $(sysconfdir)/myprg/
myprgfoodir = $(sysconfdir)/myprg/foo
```

and then

```
dist_myprg_DATA = 
dist_myprgfoo_DATA =
```

But, I wonder if a better way to do something like this exists!

Comment: Is there some reason why your method (an empty target) is bad?

Comment: `make install` doesn't make the directory if the `_DATA` list is empty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
install-data-local:
    $(MKDIR_P) $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/myprg/foo

uninstall-local:
    rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/myprg/foo 2>/dev/null || :
```

You have to specify `AC_PROG_MKDIR_P` in `configure.ac` as well.